# Insert function using foldl/foldr

Tags: sml, ml, mosml

I have been working on a separate function that returns a list that inserts element x after each k elements of list l (counting from
the end of the list). For example, separate (1, 0, [1,2,3,4]) should return [1,0,2,0,3,0,4]. I finished the function and have it working as follows:

```
fun separate (k: int, x: 'a, l: 'a list) : 'a list = 
  let
    fun kinsert [] _ = []
      | kinsert ls 0 = x::(kinsert ls k)
      | kinsert (l::ls) i = l::(kinsert ls (i-1))
  in
     List.rev (kinsert (List.rev l) k)
  end
```

Im now trying to simplify the function using foldl/foldr without any recursion, but I cant seem to get it working right. Any tips/suggestions on how to approach this? Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are more or less the thoughts I had when trying to write the function using `foldl`/`foldr`:

- `foldl`/`foldr` abstracts away the list recursion from the logic that composes the end result.
- Start by sketching out a function that has a much similar structure to your original program, but where `foldr` is used and `kinsert` instead of being a recursive function is the function given to `foldr`:

  ```
  fun separate (k, x, L) =
      let fun kinsert (y, ys) = ...
      in foldr kinsert [] L
      end
  ```

  This isn't strictly necessary; `kinsert` might as well be anonymous.
- You're using an inner helper function `kinsert` because you need a copy of `k` (`i`) that you gradually decrement and reset to `k` every time it reaches 0. So while the list that `kinsert` spits out is equivalent to the fold's accumulated variable, `i` is *temporarily* accumulated (and occasionally reset) in much the same way.
- Change `kinsert`'s accumulating variable to make room for `i`:

  ```
  fun separate (k, x, L) =
      let fun kinsert (y, (i, xs)) = ...
      in foldr kinsert (?, []) L
      end
  ```

  Now the result of the fold becomes `'a * 'a list`, which causes two problems: 1) We only really wanted to accumulate `i` *temporarily*, but it's part of the final result. This can be circumvented by discarding it using `#2 (foldr ...)`. 2) If the result is now a tuple, I'm not sure what to put as the first `i` in place of `?`.
- Since `kinsert` is a separate function declaration, you can use pattern matching and multiple function bodies:

  ```
  fun separate (k, x, L) =
      let fun kinsert (y, (0, ys)) = ...
            | kinsert (y, (i, ys)) = ...
      in ... foldr kinsert ... L
      end
  ```
- Your original `kinsert` deviates from the recursion pattern that a fold performs in one way: In the middle pattern, when `i` matches `0`, you're not chopping an element off `ls`, which a fold would otherwise force you to. So your `0` case will look slightly different from the original; you'll probably run into an off-by-one error.
- Remember that `foldr` actually visits the last element in the list first, at which point `i` will have its initial value, where with the original `kinsert`, the initial value for `i` will be when you're at the first element.
- Depending on whether you use `foldl` or `foldr` you'll run into different problems: `foldl` will reverse your list, but address items in the right order. `foldr` will keep the list order correct, but create a different result when `k` does not divide the length of `L`...
- At this point, consider using `foldl` and reverse the list instead:

  ```
  fun separate (k, x, L) =
      let fun kinsert (y, (?, ys)) = ...
            | kinsert (y, (i, ys)) = ...
      in rev (... foldl kinsert ... L)
      end
  ```

  Otherwise you'll start to notice that `separate (2, 0, [1,2,3,4,5])` should probably give `[1,2,0,3,4,0,5]` and not `[1,0,2,3,0,5]`.